# Recent achievement count not matching

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, achievements-dialog

Recent achievement count from the indicator and dropdown are not matching. One shows +13 while other shows +15 (3 upvotes)

[image]

The reputations tab does not show any negative reputation points

[image]

Comment: That's because you either got a downvote, or a post you edited was removed, so that you lost two rep; while you didn't check the indicator; **or** it was before the upvotes.

Comment: Did you downvote? Or get downvoted? The one in your profile is a *specific and individual* listing of rep you *earned*. The notifications bar is your difference of positive vs negative rep. So 15 rep -2 rep for dvote would be right

Comment: @James No, No other upvote/downvote. That's the only change. Complete listing also shows only these 3 upvotes totalling to +15. Correct one is +15 as my earlier rep was 131 and +15 goes to 146 (current) so only the notification one is incorrect.

Comment: A post with an approved edit got removed > `-2` points. Make sure "show removed posts" is checked at bottom of your rep page.

Comment: @DavidPostill checked, but nothing in the recent times. Also as mentioned in my earlier comment total reps has increased (checked from graph) so +15 is correct.

Comment: I doubt this is a bug, or incorrect calculations (might be, but doubt it). There will be some reason - a downvote/downvoted X2; deleted post you had up and downvotes on; etc. Just need to find it, or a moderator might notice this and be able to see what it was :)

Comment: @James Updated the question with screenshot from reputations tab (with "show removed posts" ticked)

Comment: I had no doubt that's what that area looked like, but there are other things which affect rep which are not displayed in that area. Deleted items etc. Again, perhaps a moderator can confirm what exactly happened. It will be one of the things we've all suggested though ;)

Comment: @Nimesh If you add all the reps. total comes to 145 and you have 146 reps. You are still up by 1 rep. This might make you happy :)

Comment: @HackerKarma I'm trying to improve the site by reporting bugs, it could be beneficial if in case it impacts multiple sites within SE forum.

Comment: @Nimesh I agree and All I am saying that at least total reps are not down by 2 votes but up by 1. So, it's kinda bug too.

Comment: The fact this is "by design" is the real problem IMO; it's clearly confusing.  Even if the dropdown just had a "and -2 rep due to something hidden" with a link to a faq entry that would solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what likely happened.

You did get +15 yesterday and for a while, the top bar did show +15 in the green box. Then, something that gave you +2 reputation in the past has been removed.

The achievements dialog does not show such things, however the -2 does affect the overall count.

You might be able to find the culprit by ticking "show removed posts" checkbox in the reputation tab of your profile page, but this might not help if for example you suggested an edit to a post that has been deleted.

This reputation change is affected by changes from all Stack Exchange sites you are already registered with, so you will have to check reputation tab on profiles on all those sites too.

Comment: updated the question with screenshot from reputations tab, it does not show any negative rep. Is this correct?

Comment: @Nimesh Have you ever suggested an edit here on MSE? Or downvoted an answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard see might comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263364/recent-achievement-count-not-matching#comment856738_263364

Comment: @ShadowWizard no votes (up/down) and no suggested edits on MSE

Comment: @ShadowWizard what if the OP's downvoted answer or user gets deleted then he may get +1 back, right? Then total will be 146 (145 + 1)  But, OP says he has not DV any answer, so that makes this harder to analyze

Comment: @HackerKarma Could it be because of downvote on some other forum but not shown on the notification dropdown?

Comment: @Nimesh Good question... but I don't think achievement reps. are combined...

Comment: Found it, there's a -2 on SO from yesterday which did not appear on notification

Comment: @Nimesh so achievements are combined total then, right?

Comment: yes, they are combined on the main notification. But since this neg rep was not shown in the dialog I thought it's some calculation bug. Not sure if this is another bug of not showing some items in the dialog. It was because of removal of post where a suggested edit was present.

Comment: @Nimesh good catch! Totally forgot it's cross site. Feel free to post your own answer with the full details.