# Recent achievements shows +1, but nothing listed

Tags: feature-request, achievements-dialog

I know it corresponds to a downvoted answer deleted, but I have no idea where on the network it is.

(And then it disappears.)

This *is* a duplicate of [Recent achievement count not matching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263364/147650) but I want it mentioned separately because it's not *just* a different count to what's displayed.

Perhaps a solution could be a tooltip that just mentions all network sites with changed reputations in the last seven days, just to give us a hint where to look.

Comment: For anyone actually wanting to help, I did actually find it, manually.

Comment: So what is the question you really want to ask? For what I am concerned, it is the same problem as in the duplicate with the same 'solution' (none).

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeah, I know it's the same problem, it just looks different when it's isolated. I've changed it to a feature request anyway.